# Is $3^{\log_{10}(3)}$ irrational?

Tags: number-theory, irrational-numbers, diophantine-approximation

After looking at it for a while it seems quite a hard problem. I am not an expert in the area, but I have the impression that it might me an open problem.

Comment: You might think, absurdly, that $3^{\log_{10}(3)}$ is a rational of the $m/n$ type.

Comment: Where does the problem come from?

Comment: @saulspatz just a friend of mine posing the question, it seems a rather natural/well-known type of question.

Answer (score 4):

This would follow from [Schanuel's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schanuel%27s_conjecture).  It implies in particular that there are no "non-obvious" algebraic relations between logarithms of algebraic numbers.

Assume that $3^{\log_{10} 3}= r$, with $r$ algebraic. Then we would have 
$$\frac{\log r}{\log 3}=\frac{\log 3}{\log 10}$$
that is, 
$$(\log 3)^2 = \log r \log 10$$

Now, $\log r$ would have to be a rational combination of $\log 3$, $\log 10$, so this implies an algebraic relation between $\log 3$ and $\log 10$, not possible.

Answer (score 0):

According to Alan Baker (A concise introduction to the theory of numbers), Lindemann proved in his proof of the trascendance of $\pi$, several other facts, in particular the trascendance of $\log(\alpha)$ for algebraic $\alpha\ne0,1$.(this theorem says: For algebraic numbers, distinct, $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\cdots,\alpha_n$ and arbitrary algebraic numbers $\beta_1,\beta_2,\cdots,\beta_n$ distinct of zero, one has $\sum\beta_ie^{\alpha_i}\ne0$).

Taking this into account $\log 3$ is trascendent and to
$x=3^{\log(3)}$ does not apply Gelfond-Schneider theorem. As far as I know $x$ can be rational (even integer) or irrational algebraic or trascendent if we want to apply the known theory.